# AppExchange Security Review Requiring Fee Submission for FREE Listing Solution

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, security-review, partner-portal, second-generation-packaging

Hope you are having a great day.

We have developed an AppExchange solution to be listed. The solution's pricing model is set to free and the listing is submitted for approval. I have completed everything necessary for the solution's security review. Upon security review submission, it says "**A security review fee applies to this submission**" and it is calculated based on the pricing model selected in the solution listing. Screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/8R9MSlz

Based on the ISV Force Documentation, [Free solutions do not have any security review fees](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review_fees.htm?q=fees). However, in this case, it is asking for a security review submission fee. Thus, I need your assistance in determining if I'm missing something or if is it something unusual.

Your help in this matter will be highly appreciated.
Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer in the partner community from one of the members of the Salesforce AppExchange Team. "sorry for the confusion! For the time being, partners with free apps need to actually log a case to request a fee waiver code until our submission payment infrastructure gets updated to accommodate free apps".

So, unless the infrastructure is updated, to submit the security review we need to log a case to get the waiver code.

Comment: Could you please share the link to the post?