# Do we have to pay $999 fee payment for any subsequent attempts of managed package security review on partner portal?

Tags: managed-package, security-review, partner-portal

We submitted our Salesforce application (managed package) for Salesforce Security review, using the Partner Portal account(as we need to list the application on Salesforce AppExchange) and were charged 999$ for the security review. Before submitting the application for security review, we did all the required scans as well and submitted the reports on the Partner Account.

After the security review, we were shared some suggestion for the managed package and were asked to make the updates for the same, then re-submit for the Security review. When we created a new version of the managed package with the suggestions done, we are being again asked to pay 999$ for Salesforce security review.

Since our application(Managed Package) has still not been listed/published on Salesforce AppExchange, we should not be charged again for listing and submitting the application for the Salesforce security review.

Did anyone recently submit the managed package for security review on partner portal and face the same issue. Please suggest me if anyhow, I can get fee waiver from Salesforce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes , we need to pay **$999** for each security review attempt.
This has been mentioned in [this](https://partners.salesforce.com/pdx/s/pcnews/appexchange-security-review-fee-updates-MC4W7STFOTRNCO5C52G27DQK5J7Y?language=en_US) article.
New policy has taken effect from March'23.

We had recently submitted and cleared the review. We were granted wavier in fees since Salesforce had incorrectly flagged some issues in our package.
Fee wavier is possible only if there is some discrepancy from Salesforce side else you will have to pay **$999**.

The review is free incase your package is free for installation.

Comment: You have to follow a process to get a waiver for free app submissions and enter the waiver code during the submission. See [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/404523/appexchange-security-review-requiring-fee-submission-for-free-listing-solution).

Comment: Since my application is paid add-on. Could you please suggest me how can we get fee-waiver for my app submission for security review ?

Comment: @KapilSaini :  Like I said in the answer , you simply cannot unless there is some mistake from Salesforce side and they agree on it.Also , it took us 4 weeks to get the wavier after multiple meetings with Salesforce.

Comment: @Rohit Ok, I will look after it,Thanks for your time.